# Is it possible to get all term items from a custom taxonomy regardless of post attachment status?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Essentially, I build web sites with galleries, for photographers.
Up until now, gallery images have all been attached to posts and I've just pulled from the category taxonomy. This is messy if it's also to be used as a regular blog.

So I've been poking around and I discovered things like if an attachment item isn't assigned to a post, it has a `parent_post ID` of **0**.

If I could, how would I go about simply getting all items with a term in my custom taxonomy, ignoring their `parent_post IDs`?

I'm getting the feeling Wordpress just isn't quite there yet, for what I would like to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you need all attachments (attached or not) with specified term?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'my_taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy_term'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ):
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        // your stuff here

    endwhile;
}
// Don't forget to reset
wp_reset_postdata();
```

[WP_Query Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: I don't know where you went wrong, or where I was going wrong extending your code... But I couldn't get it to work. But your logic I agreed with so I did some more digging over at the codex and found http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_all_attachments
THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [get_terms function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Here is an example use (from Codex):

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );
```

Comment: I've realised I wasn't being clear! I don't want the terms, I want the items with a particular term. From what I understand, I'd have to use a loop to catch all of the attachment items with and without posts attached. 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list